# Is there any way to cleanse column having different date formats in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, str-to-date

I need to cleanse a column in a table having different date formats.

eg :

> `%d-%b-%y,  %Y-%B-%d,  %d/%m/%Y, %d%b%y, %Y-%b-%d, %Y-%m-%d, %d %b %y, %m/%d/%Y`

and so on

Now i need to convert all date values to uniform format like **

> %Y-%m-%d

**.

Comment: What is your column data type?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update table data. You can use STR_TO_DATE() function to convert into date.

for e.g.,

```
UPDATE table1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d-%b-%y') WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d-%b-%y') IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE table1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%Y-%B-%d') WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%Y-%B-%d') IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE table1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d/%m/%Y') WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE table1 = STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d%b%y') WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column1, '%d%b%y') IS NOT NULL;
```

etc......

Comment: how to differentiate month and date with cases like this?  select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2015-08-09', '%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%b-%d')   , DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2015-08-09', '%Y-%d-%m'),'%Y-%b-%d') ; it returns different results